# counting number of rows which is not null and input to a table

Tags: c#, datatable, count

In my datatables i have 5 columns Workorder,date out,name handover,date in,name care. I would like to count the number of rows in the column date out and date in to check how many workorder has been done from each centers. But from my code it is showing my count query instead of the number.

```
private DataTable GetSummaryTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("center", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Counter ");
        dt.Columns.Add("Print Date");
        dt.Columns.Add("Printed by");
        dt.Columns.Add("sign");

        return dt;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        string c1 = "select COUNT(*) AS [DATE] FROM [c1 barcode] WHERE [date out]<>null ";
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(c1, connection))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        string c1care = "select COUNT(*) AS [DATE] FROM [c1 barcode] WHERE [date in]<>null ";
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(c1care, connection))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        string c2 = "select COUNT(*) AS [DATE] FROM [c2 barcode] WHERE [date out]<>null ";
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(c2, connection))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        string c2care = "select COUNT(*) AS [DATE] FROM [c2 barcode] WHERE [date in]<>null ";
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(c2care, connection))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        summarydata = GetSummaryTable();
        summarydata.Rows.Add("c1",c1, DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy"),label4.Text);
        summarydata.Rows.Add("c1_care",c1care, DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy"), label4.Text);
        summarydata.Rows.Add("c2",c2, DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy"), label4.Text);
        summarydata.Rows.Add("c2_care",c2care, DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy"), label4.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = summarydata;
    }
```

[image: What i have gotten with the code]

Comment: Why wouldn't it show your count query? You're adding the contents of the string containing the query to the datatable, not the result of the query (which is currently being discarded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your query result to variable. For example:

```
count_result = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

And next replace the variable instead of c1

```
summarydata.Rows.Add("c1",count_result , DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy"),label4.Text);
```